# Globalizing Feigin--Frenkel duality

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, w-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra, $\mathfrak{g}^L$ be its Langlands dual. Feigin--Frenkel duality says
$$
W^k(\mathfrak{g})=W^{k_L}(\mathfrak{g}^L)
$$
if $r'(k+h^{'})(k_L+h'_L)=1$, where $r'$ is the maximum number of edges between two vertices in the Dynkin diagram of $\mathfrak{g}$, $h'$ (resp. $h'_L$) is the dual Coxeter number of $\mathfrak{g}$ (resp. $\mathfrak{g}_L$).

A degeneration of this result when $k_L$ tends to infinity was used as local input by Beilinson--Drinfeld to establish some results on geometric Langlands (which was globalized using the theory of chiral algebras). Regarding the non-degenerate result, they say "We do not know if this “doubly quantized” picture
can be globalized." Has the non-degenerate result been globalized in some way since then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Feigin-Frenkel isomorphism is globalized by the global quantum geometric Langlands conjecture, proposed by Stoyanovsky, and refined by Gaitsgory and his collaborators.  See [Gaitsgory's 2016 collection of conjectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05279), in particular the discussion on page 5.

At irrational level, this appears to be (almost?) a theorem, with a major missing piece worked out earlier this year by [Arakawa and E. Frenkel](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.01536).  However, the language in the introduction and section 2 of that paper does not inspire complete confidence.  The key sentence is on page 7:

> According to Gaitsgory [Gai2], a Ran space version of this statement can be used to prove the existence of the quantum geometric Langlands correspondence $\mathbb{L}_\kappa$ discussed in the Introduction.

and [Gai2] refers to a video of a 2018 lecture rather than a published paper.

Comment: Any comments why FF is similar to Stoynovsky? Would be helpful...

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the sentence in Arakawa-Frenkel. The result proved there leads to a construction of the "master chiral algebra", which indeed produces a functor from the LHS to the RHS. However, I don't think it is clear that this functor is an equivalence (but maybe this is my ignorance speaking). More generally, my understanding is that global quantum geometric Langlands is still a ways away from being a theorem.

Comment: @dhy That is entirely possible.  I was rather surprised by Arakawa's announcement at a conference earlier this year, but I may have misinterpreted the scope of his claims.